# A good way of leaving code writers information inside HTML?

Tags: html

I'm wondering, what would be the best way of leaving code writers (programmers) information/initials/(maybe even) copyright... *well, some information about web developer, not content maintainer* inside HTML.

Is leaving a link to my site inside footer a good way, or I there maybe can used `<meta>` tags for something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want that to be visible to the end user or not?

Comment: maybe you want to ask your client on that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want that to be visible to the end user or not?

If not, use comments:

**HTML**

```
<!-- comment here -->
```

**CSS**

```
/* comment here */
```

**Javascript**

```
// comment

/* multi-line
comment*/
```

If yes, most of the times it'll be on the bottom, along with other copyright information.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about comments! Since this is a good explanation, giving answer to you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just place HTML comments near the start of the document.

```
<!--
     Page Design Copyright © 2010 My Design company,
     All rights reserved.

     http://example.com 
-->
```

**meta** elements aren't usually used for this sort of thing as they apply to the content of the current page.

Comment: Just make sure you don't place it before the doctype. This will put IE6 in quirks mode. I couldn't find the original article where I read this, but here is a [comment](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/953-IE-Has-Correct-Box-Model-In-Standards-Compliant-Mode.htm#comments_5869) that says the same thing.

Comment: Good point.  IE doesn't like stuff before the doctype.